# Put jquery+ajax into PHP while loop (all of which is inside of Ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, while-loop

I have a while loop that fetches and echos status updates.  I am trying to echo a "REPOST" link during my while loop, so that it appends to any status update (sits below it), and when clicked, passes the ID thru to an external .php file.   This link is jquery+ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', 'a[id^=repost]', function(){
    var thePostID = $(this).prop('id').split('-')[1];
    //this now has the id of the $row['id'] we declared earlier.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'reposthandler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'id' : thePostID},
        success: function(data){  
        }
     });
});
</script>


<?php

include ('time.php');


$query = "SELECT poster, posterpic, category, type, date, id, follow.beingfollowed 
FROM usergen LEFT JOIN follow ON follow.beingfollowed = usergen.poster WHERE   
follow.iwannafollow 
= '*".$loggedin."' ORDER BY usergen.date DESC ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()) ;


$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row['ago'] = ago($row['date']);
    $rows[] = $row;


    echo '<br />';
    echo '<img src="' . $row['posterpic'] . '" width="40px" height="50px">';
    echo '<font color="red" size=2px><i>';
    echo '<a>'.$row['poster'].'</a></i></font>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo $row['category'] . ' for ' . $row['type'] . ' (' . $row['ago'] . ')';
    echo '<a href="#" id="repost-',$row['id'],'">REPOST</a>';
    echo '<br /><br /><HR size="4" width="auto" color="white">';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

The links are dead and do not link thru to anything.  Why is this?  Do I need to add something below "success: function(data)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Simply add an element to the loop for the button. 

echo '<a href="#" id="repost-',$row['id'],'"> Repost This </a>';
```

Bind the click function to a static parent element.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[id^=repost]', function(){
    var thePostID = $(this).prop('id').split('-')[1];
    //this now has the id of the $row['id'] we declared earlier.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/my/controller.ext?postID='+thePostID,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){
          //do whatever with the response.
        }
    });
});
```

Now you're being passed the ID of the post you want to repost, and you can handle it however you want in your back end php file.

Comment: So, I have implemented your solution, but it seems as though the link "Repost This" does not do anything -- as in it is not grabbing the custom URL that I input where you have 'path/to/my/controller.ext'.  What would be causing this?

Comment: @Mike inside of the click function, do a `console.log(thePostID)`. If you structured the HTML just as I've shown you above in the echo, then the `<a>` tag will have an id of `repost-137` where 137 represents the ROW ID  of the post. The above click function constructs a variable by splitting the ID into an array on the `-`, then taking the last piece, or `[1]` in this scenario. The url to your file should really be the only piece missing here.

Comment: @Mike If you are sending it to a file called `myFile.php` within a folder struture of `/var/www/mydirectory/somelocation/anotherlocation/myfile.php`, then that's the URL. We send over a POST type, so the check for the variable should be `if($_POST['postID']):` which will then give you access to the variable we're passing over.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  Any idea why when I click one repost button, ALL the buttons act as if they are being pressed?  When I check my database, it's as if each button is being pressed, and each one is posting the correct information.  The problem is, I only want one click firing the one button I am clicking! : )

Comment: @Mike [Nope. The reality is that if you structure your HTML and jQuery right this won't be a problem](http://jsfiddle.net/g78ju/). Are you by chance trying to do this assignment within a `for each` or `each` or `while` loop? That would cause this type of issue.

Comment: I do have it in a 'while' loop...The reason being is that I essentially have to return a large array of posts, each having their own button.  Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: @Mike Remove the javascript from the while loop. I consructed the click function so that it attaches to **any** element that has an id that starts with `repost`, so there's no need to do this. Just move the function I wrote for you into a static loading file that is not within a `loop function`.

Comment: can you check my code?  What's still wrong? I've revised my post to reflect the updated code.

Comment: @Mike You had malformed HTML that was injecting the document with a poor structure. Also, you should maintain cohesive coding styles throughout. No reason to open echo's with `"` when you plan on re-using `"` in the string. Just open with a single `'`. Also, I've just tested this code that's above in your post (by creating fictitious table elements) and it's working as intended. Also, ensure you have an existing row of `id`, otherwise this will not work, as we can never pass over the ID to the server, and the $_POST var will return empty.

Comment: If we can't pass the ID over the server, how do I capture it inside of my external .php page? I tried using 'if ($_POST['postID']'. Maybe I'm using it incorrectly?

Comment: and is my external php link structured alright?  I do not need 'reposthandler.php?id=' correct?

Comment: Would you mind posting the .php code you used to handle the postID and that you used to insert into your tables?

Comment: I'm so close to getting this. My repost ids are populating with 'repost-1284' and other is numbers so I know it's working. My php is just not receiving the Id for some reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16339/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-mike)